# How to access header component in home.vue in Vue js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I need to hide a button in header by accessing the component inside Home.vue using Javascript. Could anyone suggest any syntax?

I tried to get elementID of the button inside Home.vue, but still it's not accessible.

Comment: It was great if you had provided some code, but anyway, I guess you're trying to query element before it's mounted to the DOM. Are you using `getElementById` in the mounted hook? (or any hooks after that)

Comment: Maybe you can reference it with the `ref`attribute ? https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

Comment: This sounds like a good scenario for state management. Passing data across components that are not parent-child requires an event bus, which is not a good solution when it can be avoided using a central store like Vuex.

Comment: There are many ways. In your `Home` component you can emit an event to hide, and keep re-emitting it until reaching the `Header` parent component and then passing the property to manage that. Another option is starting to use vuex to manage the state and create a flag to manage that. So, in the `Home` component you dispatch an action to change this flag.

Answer (score 0):

Use `event bus` or store that variable in `Vuex` so you can access and mutate that variable